# IndentationError when pasting code in Python 3 interpreter mode

Tags: python

When I was running the following code, which has blank lines (no space) inside functions, I got different behavior from Python 3.6.5 when running the code line by line in interpreter mode and `python3 split.py`:

```
# File split.py

def find(s, start, predictor):
    for i in range(start, len(s)):
        if predictor(s[i]):
            return i
    return -1

def find_all(s, sep=" \t\n"):
    beg_of_nonsep = 0
    while beg_of_nonsep < len(s):
        beg_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch not in sep_chs)
        if beg_of_nonsep == -1:
            break

        end_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep + 1, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch in sep_chs)
        if end_of_nonsep == -1:
            end_of_nonsep = len(s)

        yield (beg_of_nonsep, end_of_nonsep)

        beg_of_nonsep = end_of_nonsep + 1

split = lambda s: [s[beg: end] for (beg, end) in find_all(s)]

print(split(""))
print(split("     \t\n"))
print(split("     \tssss\n"))
```

When running the code line by line in interpreter mode, `python3` gave me nasty errors:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def find(s, start, predictor):
...     for i in range(start, len(s)):
...         if predictor(s[i]):
...             return i
...     return -1
...
>>> def find_all(s, sep=" \t\n"):
...     beg_of_nonsep = 0
...     while beg_of_nonsep < len(s):
...         beg_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch not in sep_chs)
...         if beg_of_nonsep == -1:
...             break
...
>>>         end_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep + 1, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch in sep_chs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    end_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep + 1, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch in sep_chs)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         if end_of_nonsep == -1:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if end_of_nonsep == -1:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             end_of_nonsep = len(s)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    end_of_nonsep = len(s)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>>         yield (beg_of_nonsep, end_of_nonsep)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    yield (beg_of_nonsep, end_of_nonsep)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>>         beg_of_nonsep = end_of_nonsep + 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    beg_of_nonsep = end_of_nonsep + 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>> split = lambda s: [s[beg: end] for (beg, end) in find_all(s)]
>>>
>>> print(split(""))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>> print(split("     \t\n"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>> print(split("     \tssss\n"))
```

And the last `print` here never quit until I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to stop it.

Thus, I thought there were many bugs with my code.

However, when I ran the code with `python3 split.py`, none of this happened:

```
[]
[]
['ssss']
```

This is rather confusing to me.

To be clear, I was actually using [vimcmdline](https://github.com/jalvesaq/vimcmdline) on Debian 9.8 with vim 8.1.

I am also using `pylint` through `pymode`, which split any trailing space, of which it considered superfluous.

This problem happened when I tried to use its builtin keybinding to send `split.py` to the `python3` in the `tmux` split it opened.

I have already filled an [issue](https://github.com/jalvesaq/vimcmdline/issues/60), but I can't help wonder why `python3` behaves like this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This behaviour doesn't look surprising to me.

Python uses indentation to determine the beginning and end of a code block.  Logically indentation ends on the first line that *isn't* indented.  When running scripts blank lines are ignored.  And when running scripts this means that indentation ends either with an un-indented line or the end of file.

But this behaviour cannot work in a command line mode because there is no end of file.  Consider the following script file:

```
from somewhere import bar, do_something

for foo in bar:
    do_something(foo)
```

In a script, the end of the file indicates that it should now run the for loop.  It knows there is no more to execute.  But in command line mode, the command line is still open, you can still write more.  It has no idea whether or not your next line of code is going to be inside or outside the for loop.  But the command line cannot just sit and wait for your next line of code... you want it to execute ... now!

Therefore the command line operates with one specific difference.  A blank line will also end a code block.  So this is fine:

```
from somewhere import bar, do_something, do_something_else

for foo in bar:
    do_something(foo)
    do_something_else(foo)
```

But this is an error:

```
from somewhere import bar, do_something, do_something_else

for foo in bar:
    do_something(foo)

    do_something_else(foo)
```

Because you have already ended the for loop with a blank line and cannot add to it.

Comment: This is a good explanation. It’s worth noting that the interpreter _could_ have been designed such that it always waits for an unindented line, which effectively means that when you want it to “execute…now!” you should type an unindented `pass`. Presumably all this extra `pass`ing was deemed more annoying than the incompatibility with the actual language.

Comment: What I do to fix this is replace all \n\n with \n until there are no more double line breaks and then paste into python interpreter.

Comment: in short, remove blank lines while pasting to CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a continuation character '\' at the end of the line, just before blank lines within a function definition (at least for this code sample which only includes functions, e.g. no classes or other constructs that would be terminated to early by a blank line).

Below shows how the continuation characters allow the code to be pasted:

```
>>> def find_all(s, sep=" \t\n"):
...     beg_of_nonsep = 0
...     while beg_of_nonsep < len(s):
...         beg_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch not in sep_chs)
...         if beg_of_nonsep == -1:
...             break                               \
... 
...         end_of_nonsep = find(s, beg_of_nonsep + 1, lambda ch, sep_chs=sep: ch in sep_chs)
...         if end_of_nonsep == -1:
...             end_of_nonsep = len(s)              \
... 
...         yield (beg_of_nonsep, end_of_nonsep)    \
... 
...         beg_of_nonsep = end_of_nonsep + 1
... 
>>> split = lambda s: [s[beg: end] for (beg, end) in find_all(s)]
```

I'm not suggesting this is a great solution, but it does work.